# Connect to mysql server in ubuntu running in VMware Fusion using mysql Workbench

Tags: ssh, mysql, 22.04, vmware-fusion

```
guest OS ---> Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
host OS ----> MacOS 12.5.1
VMware Fusion: Player Version 12.2.4 (20071091)
mysql: Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
mysql Workbench 8.0.30
```

I'm trying to configure mysql Workbench to connect to a mysql server hosted in a virtual machine. I own and control both host and guest OSs and the mysql server.

I can connect to the Ubuntu machine via VMware's Connect to SSH option. This uses server 172.yy.yy.yy and port 22. I also provided the u/name and p/wd for the Ubuntu OS. That all work fine and I can sudo into mysql using that. I can also log in using another user that has host 'localhost'.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I should enter into mysql workbench in order to connect though. I have created a remote access user that has as host the ip address of the MacOS (I got this just by googling 'my ip').

I have also edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config to include: `ListenAddress xx.xx.xx.xx` (where xx.xx.xx.xx is my host OS's IP address).

Connection Method: I've selected `Standard TCP/IP over SSH`

SSH Hostname: `my_guest_OS's_IP_address`

SSH Username: `my_guest_OS's_username`

SSH Password: `my_guest_OS's_username's_pwd`

MySQL Hostname: `0.0.0.0`

MySQL Server Port: `22`

Username: `my_remote_mysql_login_name`

Password: `my_remote_mysql_login_pwd`

Default Schema: <leave_blank>

I am currently getting the below error message:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 0.0.0.0:22 through SSH tunnel at <my_guest_OS's_username>@<my_guest_OS's_IP_address> with user <my_remote_mysql_login_name>

Cannot open SSH Tunnel: Connection refused
```

Comment: If you’re connecting through an SSH tunnel, then the MySQL host should be 127.0.0.1 and the port should be 3306 

Comment: I get the same error message with that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUCCESS!

So after a little more research I have now connected. There were three problems.

1. **Wrong IP address**. The `SSH Hostname` was NOT discoverable by simply opening a browser and googling 'my ip'. I needed to log into the terminal and use `ip route` and then find the `src` line to get the host address for SSH.
2. I had read that I should create a separate mysql user for remote access and this should have as hostname the IP address from which I would be connecting. This turns out not to be the case. Workbench, it seems, insists on using `username@localhost` when trying to connect. So `user_remote@localhost` will always fail if the user username and host listed in the user table is actually, say `user_remote@xx.xx.xx.xx`. To get around this I just logged in with my local user. Workbench then sent `user_local@hostname` and everything worked.

```
    | user             | host        |
    +------------------+-------------+
    | user_remote      | xx.xx.xx.xx |
    | user_local       | localhost   |
    +------------------+-------------+
```

3. @matigo was correct. I needed 127.0.0.1 and 3306 in the mysql hostname and server port.